# JFrame initially appears with a maximum width limited to my monitor width

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm experiencing a strange problem with the java `JFrame` class in one of my programs. Thankfully I'm able to duplicate this issue using the `FrameDemo.java` example taken from Oracle's website:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FrameDemoProject/src/components/FrameDemo.java

I change the dimension of `emptyLabel` to (3005, 100) and then compile and launch the program.  On my dual monitor display, I expect the frame to almost span both monitors (they're each 1920 pixels wide).

Instead, what I'm seeing is that the `JFrame` is sized to fit the width of a single monitor.  I can't seems to get the window to come up spanning both monitors.  Am I doing something wrong here?  I'm running on Centos 7.5 and am using jdk 1.8.0_60.

The exact code appears below.  It's mostly a copy/paste from Oracle's demo, with some comments cut to keep it short.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* FrameDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class FrameDemo {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("blahblah");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3005, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This "may" be a limitation of the OS

Comment: I'm starting to think this might be the case.  I have learned that a JFrame is associated with a GraphicsConfiguration (gc).  As all my gc devices are 1920x1080 in size, I'm starting to think that the JFrame may be limited to this size.

Comment: Interestingly, if I call frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension 3500,100)); just prior to the pack statement, the window comes up spanning both monitors.  I don't want to do this in a real program though.

Comment: Yes and no. You can have window larger than the physical screen, although on MacOS you'll be disappointed by the results.  After a "lot" of digging, it appears that the call to `setVisible` is actually the culprit.  `pack` will honour the preferred size of the contents, but for some reason after calling `setVisible`, the window is constrained to the size of the monitor and I can't find exactly "where" this is getting done.  "A" somewhat "nasty" solution would to call `pack` (again) after calling `setVisible` 

Comment: That's not nasty - it's a beautiful workaround for a nasty problem!  How did you figure that out?

Comment: I put a bunch of print statements before after each call, showing the preferred size and actual size of the window.  I could be in the native peer layer, it could be in the delegate look and feel layout, it could be somewhere in the layout logic, I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to MadProgrammer.  Unfortunately, in my more complicated program, the second call to pack didn't seem to do the trick.

The workaround I eventually settled on was to compute the cumulative width of all my components (they were loaded into a JSplitPane). This is equal to the widths of the left pane, the right pane and the divider.  If this cumulative width exceeds the width of a monitor, I set frame minimum size to this cumulative width. This seems to ensure that the frame can span two monitors when it appears.  Then after making things visible, I reset the minimum size to a value I saved at startup time.  This allows my JFrame to come up on two screens but still be resizable to something smaller.

This truly is a nasty workaround.  I have reported this as a bug to http://bugs.java.com.  It's listed as the following bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8213620